# Linq Order by based on Or condition

Tags: c#, linq

This is how my EF Model Responses table looks like

```
Question_ID         Responce

1                   Agree
1                   Agree
1                   Tend to Agree
1                   Tend to Agree

2                   Agree
2                   Agree
2                   Tend to Agree
2                   Tend to DisAgree

3                   DisAgree
3                   DisAgree
3                   Tend to DisAgree
3                   Tend to DisAgree
```

in the above eg. i want to sort by Question ID based on Agree(Agree should include Tend to Agree also while counting) and DisAgree. DisAgree should include Tend to Disagree also while counting)

Hence Agree order Should as below

```
1 // (Got 4 Agree)
2 // (Got 3 Agree)
3 // (Got 0 Agree)
```

Disgaree Should as below

```
3 // (Got 4 Disagree)
2 // (Got 1 Disagree)
1 // (Got 0 Disagree)
```

Simle Linq to order based on total responce Count.
I am expecting modified linq based on above requirement

```
db.Questions.OrderBy(x => x.Responces.Count).Select(y=>new { y.Question_ID,count= y.Responces.Count()}).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you try `db.Questions.OrderBy(x => x.Responces.Count(r => r.Contains("DisAgree") == false)).ToList();` if this would do what you want?

Comment: Your requirements don't match the LINQ used. How are you going to get an individual ID from a group? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, by the way, and it doesn't seem like you tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

You cant group by two keys simultaniously. One Group needs one unique key.

What you could to however is the following:

```
db.Questions.GroupBy(x=>((x.Responce == "Agree")|(x.Responce == "Tend
to Agree")));
```

This will give you two keys `TRUE` and `FALSE`. In the `TRUE` group are all values that have `"Agree"` or `"Tend to Agree"`. In the `FALSE` group there will be all others.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you convert your response-column to an enum type like this one:

```
[Flags]
public enum Response
{
    Agree = 1,
    Unknown = 2,
    Disagree = 4,
    TendToAgree = Agree | Unknown,
    TendToDisagree = Unknown | Disagree
}
```

That way you check for the flag you want and count the entries:

```
var agreed = list.Where(x => x.QuestionID == 1).Count(x => x.Response.HasFlag(Response.Agree));
var disagreed = list.Where(x => x.QuestionID == 1).Count(x => x.Response.HasFlag(Response.Disagree));
```